# How merge expression in the Select method with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, expression

I am trying to make a generic to be used on the Selectors components. It should provide a default pattern result which is based on a type we have made called `SelectorViewModel` that has an `Id`, a `Description` and a `Code`. Today we have a method that does it using the following query:

```
var result = Queryable.Where(x => .... )
                      .OrderBy(x => ... )
                      .Select(x => SelectorViewModel(x.Id, 
                                                     x.Name, 
                                                     x.Code))
                      .ToList();
```

It works fine, but we will have a lot of these methods. The question is, how to make the fields defined on the `Select` method to be possible to pass as parameter to the `SelectorViewModel`? For sample:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectorViewModel> Selector<T>(.. idExpression, .. descriptionExpression, .. codeExpression)
{
    var result = session.Query<T>
                        .Where(x => .... )
                        .OrderBy(x => ... )
                        .Select(x => SelectorViewModel(idExpression,  // id
                                                       descriptionExpression, // description
                                                       codeExpression /*code*/))
                        .ToList();

   return result;
}
```

I would like to have something like this on the use of this method:

```
var result = repository.Selector(x => x.Id, x => x.Name, x => x.Code);
```

And make these arguments be merged on the expression on the `Select` method. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: make those idExpression, descriptionExpression and codeExpression generic functions themselves. Then call `SelectorViewModel(idExpression(x), descriptionExpression(x), codeExpression(x))`

Comment: should it be `Func<T, long>`? With `Expression<Func<T, long>>` does not work.

Comment: What is the type of the `Id`, `Description` and `Code`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectorViewModel> Selector<T>(
        Func<T, int> idExpression, 
        Func<T, string> descriptionExpression,
        Func<T, string> codeExpression)
    {
        var result = session.Query<T>
                 .Where(x => .... )
                 .OrderBy(x => ... )
                 .Select(x => new SelectorViewModel(idExpression(x), descriptionExpression(x), codeExpression(x)))
                 .ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

However I prefer something more like a "Factory method", so that you pass a factory that convert T to SelectorViewModel (something like this):

```
public class SelectorViewModel
{
    public static SelectorViewModel GetSelectorViewModel<T>(T input)
    {
        //create SelectorViewModel how do you prefer
        return new SelectorViewModel(input.Id, input.Description, input.Code);
    }

    public SelectorViewModel(int id, string description, int code)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectorViewModel> Selector<T>(Func<T, SelectorViewModel> factoryMethod)
{
     var result = session.Query<T>
                 .Where(x => .... )
                 .OrderBy(x => ... )
                 .Select(x => factoryMethod(x))
                 .ToList();
     return result;
}
```

this because (personally) I don't like to pass many functions, maybe complex such as:

```
x => x.property > 2 ? x.name.ToString() : (x.property < 0 ? x.description : x.description + "a")
```

and, at the end

- the code is less readable
- no/low support for debugging
- long code line (length)

[ps: what I did above can be done with OOP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)]

Comment: You said about Factory Method, how would you implement it @Sierrodc?

Comment: Edited with some comments. Btw, if you need something really simple, first solution should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I think a factory method should be nice, but it is so simple, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From your samples it's not quite clear what query provider are you targeting (EF or NHibernate), so the following is an universal helper method which composes selector expression using prototype expression and small `ExpressionVisitor` based parameter replacer:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<SelectorViewModel> ToSelectorViewModel<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source, 
        Expression<Func<T, long>> idSelector,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> descriptionSelector,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> codeSelector
    )
    {
        Expression<Func<long, string, string, SelectorViewModel>> prototype =
            (id, description, code) => new SelectorViewModel { Id = id, Description = description, Code = code };
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var body = prototype.Body
            .ReplaceParameter(prototype.Parameters[0], idSelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(idSelector.Parameters[0], parameter))
            .ReplaceParameter(prototype.Parameters[1], descriptionSelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(descriptionSelector.Parameters[0], parameter))
            .ReplaceParameter(prototype.Parameters[2], codeSelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(codeSelector.Parameters[0], parameter));
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, SelectorViewModel>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Select(selector);
    }
}
```

The expression helper used:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Now assuming your method receives the same `idSelector`, `descriptionSelector` and `codeSelector` arguments as above, the usage would be:

```
var result = Queryable.Where(x => .... )
                      .OrderBy(x => ... )
                      .ToSelectorViewModel(idSelector, descriptionSelector, codeSelector) 
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: This is the way I interpreted the question too, I got in a pickle trying to build this expression. Very tidy solution here!

Comment: I am using NHibernate, I will check this solution too, thank Ivan.

Comment: If I concat on the parameters, for sample in the description: `x => x.FirstName + " " x.LastName`, should it work too?

Comment: @FelipeOriani You are welcome. Looks like NH is much more tolerant to invoking custom methods/funcs than EF which will immediately throw `NotSupportedException` in case you do something like in the other answer (or even just using constructor with parameters) :-) Regarding the concat, yes, it will work with any expression that returns `string`.

Comment: @Stuart Thank you! *I got in a pickle* - you've made my day, LOL :)